# Excel formula for upper triangular matrix. Rate increases

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to write a dynamic excel formula such that it does the product of rates in this way.

u and d are  some values. not necessarily sum or product to 1.

let say u = 1.15 and d = 0.9

only for upper triangular matrix, lower ones should be blanks.

illustration is till 5 but i need it in general.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Upper (Right) Triangular Matrix

**Basic**

```
=LET(u,2,d,3,n,5,low,"",
MAKEARRAY(n,n,LAMBDA(r,c,
    IF(r>c,low,u^(c-r)*d^(r-1)))))
```

[image]

**LAMBDA Formula**

In the *Name Manager*, e.g. for the name `UTM` use the following formula:

```
=LAMBDA(u,d,n,[low],LET(
    l,IF(ISOMITTED(low),"",low),
MAKEARRAY(n,n,LAMBDA(r,c,
    IF(r>c,l,u^(c-r)*d^(r-1))))))
```

Now you can simply use...

```
=UTM(2,3,5)
```

... anywhere in the workbook.

Comment: I like this approach. however i do not have office 365. anything else can you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches one is a formula, the second use Data Table

Presume that the two parameters are in K1 and L1.

**With formula**

Table is placed from cell A1 (see screenshot)

```
=IF(ROW()<=COLUMN(),$K$1^(COLUMN()-ROW())*$L$1^(ROW()-2),"")
```

**With Data Table**

Cell F17: `=IF(N1<=M1,$K$1^(M1-N1)*$L$1^(N1-1),"")`

Fill the cells horizontally and vertically with a sequence from 1 to the required length.

Select the whole range from F17. Select Data -> What-if Analysis -> Data Table. In the pop-up window select row input cell: $M$1 and column input cell: $N$1 references. Click OK.

[image]